# Hi, I am new to Codeigniter. A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: News::$News_model

Filename: controllers/News.php

Line Number: 14

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workshop10/application/controllers/News.php
Line: 14
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/workshop10/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

my controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

     public function index()
     {
          $data['theNews'] = array("All your base are belong to us!",
                                 "Autotune this news",
                                  "Numa Numa!!",
                                  $this->News_model->get_new_news()
                                );
          $this->load->view('templates/news_header');
          $this->load->view('new_items',$data);
          $this->load->view('templates/news_footer');
    }
}
```

my model:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    var $title = '';
    var $content = '';
    var $date = '';
    public function __construct()
    {
    //call the Model constuctor
    parent::__construct();
    }
    public function get_new_news()
    {
    return "Something Kool";
    }
}
```

my view:

```
 <?php
 foreach ($theNews as $news_item) { ?>
 <div><?php echo $news_item; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Error is quite clear: Message: Undefined property: News::$News_model You don't have such property ($News_model) in your Class (News)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller.Use the following code.

```
public function index()
 {
      $this->load->model('News_model');//loads your model 
      $return = $this->News_model->get_new_news();
      $data['theNews'] = array("All your base are belong to us!",
                             "Autotune this news",
                              "Numa Numa!!",
                              $return
                            );

      $this->load->view('templates/news_header');
      $this->load->view('new_items',$data);
      $this->load->view('templates/news_footer');
}
```

Comment: @J.J Glad to help you.Best of luck ahead.

Answer (score 0):

u didnt load your model file on your controller

use this`$this->load->model('News_model');`

Comment: Great! much appreciated!